# How to Play Streaming Audio/Video from a url?

Tags: android, streaming, media-player

I am new in Android. I am using android os 2.2. I am trying to play streaming audio and video from url. I don't know what to do for that. after 3 days og googling i come to know that I have to use mediaPlayer and MediaController classes.

I had use different differend combination of codes found on internet but not succeed.

Can anybody guide me what to do for streaming audio/video playing. What about the UI if we use MediaPlayer or Controller class. is there any thing to related these in xml file of layout.

if not then even please tell me what may be the code for that.

please help me.

Comment: check this link: https://github.com/abdullahfarwees/Android-Online-Radio-app

Answer (score 7):

Hope this helps.

1- Install VLC on your computer (SERVER) and go to Media->Streaming (Ctrl+S)

2- select a file to stream or if you want to stream your webcam or... click on "Capture Device" tab and do the configuration and finally click on "Stream" button.

3- here you should do the streaming server configuration, just go to "Option" tab and past the following command:

```
sout=#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,vb=400,fps=10,width=176,height=144,acodec=mp4a,ab=32,channels=1,samplerate=22050}:rtp{sdp=rtsp://YOURCOMPUTER_SERVER_IP_ADDR:5544/}**
```

**NOTE:** replace YOURCOMPUTER_SERVER_IP_ADDR with your computer IP address or any server which is running VLC...

**NOTE:** You can see, the video codec is MP4V which is supported by android.

4- go to eclipse and create a new project for media playbak. create a VideoView object and in the OnCreate() function write some code like this:

```
mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
mVideoView.setVideoPath("rtsp://YOURCOMPUTER_SERVER_IP_ADDR:5544/");
mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
```

5- run the apk on the device (not simulator, i did not check it) and wait for the playback to be started. please consider the buffering process will take about 10 seconds...

Comment: I cannot find Media->Streaming (Ctrl+S). Can you please guide me>

Comment: Sorry sir, Its Not Streaming, Its Stream(Ctrl+s).

Comment: I think we are on different versions of VLC and for it is: File -> Streaming/Exporting wizard. After that it shows a wizard that asks about each values that you have mentioned in the command above. I hope this helps someone else in the future.

Comment: Version wont be a problem. I am using VLC 2.0.5. Which Operating System You are using?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done much into multimedia, but if you're looking for streaming even via RSTP, then MediapLayer can help.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am trying different-2 combinations for MediaPlayer and MediaController. Can you please tell me any link for playing streaming .mp3s and .pls in android os 2.2

Comment: Aaron (above) has provided some good links.
What i can give as of now is: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: I got succeeded to get streaming for audios and videos the problem is Video is not getting displayed while Sound is playing perfectly. I an using Surface view any idea?

Comment: While it is an  old question ,  your problem should be in codec.