# API for streaming on Android after the abandonment of Adobe flash player

Tags: android, streaming, adobe, flash

There are API for streaming on Android?Or only solutions is HTML5?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068306/how-to-play-streaming-audio-video-from-a-url

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: What kind of streamin are tryin to do? RTSP, RTMP, M3U8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There´s no API for Streaming, use [**MediaPlayer**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html), [**VideoView**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) and even you can use the native player for streaming.