# How can I stream in android with ftp server?

Tags: java, android, ftp, protocols, nas

I can upload and download files on my android app. However, I wish to stream video and audio over 3g/4g like an 'ES File Explorer'. But the problem is I couldn't approach it.
Could anybody tell me a method about ES File Explorer's streaming skill?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Play Streaming Audio/Video from a url?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068306/how-to-play-streaming-audio-video-from-a-url)

Comment: what did you try, and what did not work, how did it fail, and did you read any learning materials (like tutorials)?

Comment: well I did using Minidlna package, but it is only used ln local. So I am trying to find another method.